# Complex Numbers Inequality from GM

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, contest-math, absolute-value

If $x,y,z$ are complex numbers such that $ |x| = |y|= |z| =1$, show that $$\vert 1+x |+ |1+y|+ |1+z| + |x+y| + |y+z| + |z+x| \geq 4$$

This is a problem from Romanian G.M. nr $11/2016$ and I couldn't solve it. I managed just to show that it is greater then $3$:

> Let $s=|1+x|+|1+y|+|1+z|+|x+y|+|y+z|+|z+x|$.
>
> Using the triangle inequality we obtain that $s\geq|3+3(x+y+z)|$.
>
> On the other hand, using that $|x+y|=|−x−y|$ we obtain that $s\geq|3−(x+y+z)|$, so $3s\geq|9−3(x+y+z)|$ and so $4s\geq12$ and thus $s\geq 3$

Comment: You asked this yesterday and had the question closed for being off topic (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2175993/401264) - don't repost exactly the same thing again without taking note of what was commented on your post yesterday. For example, show us your working to show it is greater than $3$

Comment: @lioness99a  i made the changes required

Comment: Can you show your working for it being greater than $3$?

Comment: @lioness99a Let $s=|1+x|+|1+y|+|1+z|+|x+y|+|y+z|+|z+x|$. Using the triangle inequality we obtain that $s\geqslant |3+3*(x+y+z)|$. On the other hand, using that $|x+y|=|-x-y|$ we obtain that $s\geqslant|3-(x+y+z)|$, so $3*s\geqslant|9-3*(x+y+z)|$ and so $4*s\geqslant12$.

Comment: @MyGlasses I obtained that it is grater than 3, not than 4.

Comment: @razvanelda Brilliant, thanks. I've added that to the body of the question - this is what people meant on yesterday's question when they said it needed context. Explaining what you've already done is a great way of showing that you've already thought about the problem too

Comment: @lioness99a Ok Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the triangle inequality we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(|1+x|+|x+y|\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{|1+x|+|1+y|+|-x-y|}{2}+\frac{|x+y|+|y+z|+|-x-z|}{2}\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{|1+x+1+y-x-y|}{2}+\frac{|x+y+y+z-x-z|}{2}=4.$$
Done!

Comment: For what $x$, $y$ and $z$ the equality occurs.?

Comment: @MyGlasses $x=y=-1$ and $z=1$.

Comment: Sorry, In the last term isn't $1+|y|+1+|x|+1+|z|=6$.?

Comment: @MyGlasses No! The last term it's just $|y|=1$.